# Displaying output from a PowerShell script started from PowerShell only once

Tags: powershell, output

I have been playing with PowerShell recently and wrote the following script:

```
$scriptBlock = 
{
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
  Write-Host 'Hello world!'
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
  Write-Host ([DateTime]::Now).TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
  exit -1
}

$encodedCommand = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String(
  [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($scriptBlock))

& $ps -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted `
  -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

which outputs

```
Hello world!
70803964,7878
Hello world!
70803964,7878
```

The first `Hello world` is written to console after 1 second, then there's a delay (well, it does what I want) and the milliseconds are displayed. The second half of the output is written to the console at once - like when you capture the output of the script and write it to the console.

Can anyone help - I just want the first half of the output (none of the basic redirections like `2>&1` worked.

Comment: if you do `Invoke-Command $scriptBlock` it does return only once. I assume that it does redirect all the output from the process once the process finishes.

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code you posted outputs "Hello world!" followed by a timestamp just once (after I replaced `$ps` with `powershell.exe`, that is).

Comment: Use `Write-Output` not `Write-Host`

Comment: @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF That would allow using redirection, but doesn't explain why the OP gets the output twice.

Comment: Thanks @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF, that works, but as pointed out by Ansgar, that does not explain that.